# Activity overview is glitching!

Tags: gnome, 20.04

I'm pretty new to ubuntu. Since yesterday i have been encountering this glitch in activity overview and show application. I didn't know what to do so i posted the picture here. Hope anyone here will be able to help me. Btw, this happened around same time when i was trying to use my android device as second screen which i couldn't. i tried VNS and some other things things that i don't remember well.[Picture of the problem is here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYDOl.png)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using, and are you using Dash to Dock (as it doesn't work well in 20.04)? I presume you've tried rebooting...

Comment: First disable all extensions, then log out and log in to see if the issue persists. Then reenable all extensions one by one and watch whether the issue returns. If all fails, and you don't remember what you changed in the first place, then you can reset your user account. If you did systemwide interventions, then a system reinstall may be needed if you cannot undo your changes.